# Онлайн трансляция на сайт PHP через OBS

Tags: php, obs

Мне нужно транслировать видео из OBS в свой плеер на сайте
В интернете предлагают варианты со всякими программами, вроде Adobe, но это не вариант.
Пишут, что нужно сделать свой видеосервер. RTMP или как здесь https://habr.com/ru/company/skyeng/blog/341306/ или вообще что-то такое https://gist.github.com/n3wtron/4624820#file-simple_mjpeg_streamer_http_server
Я не очень понимаю, это прямой смысл или общий? Именно сервер нужен или всё-таки такую штуку можно реализовать на обычном хостинге?
Кто-то писал про Amazon S3, но я не понял, технология это или сервер.
Я не очень понял, что нужно давать OBS Studio в пункте Вещание->Сервер.
Ссылку на скрипт?

Я не понимаю, как передавать сигнал из OBS в скрипт на сайте, куда использовать "ключ трансляции" и как реализовать этот скрипт, чтобы он получал картинку и вызывал её, а затем показывать получаемое изображение на другой странице в плеере.

Понимаю, что пишу кашу, но это всё, что я нашёл в интернете.
Возможно, Вы сможете помочь мне разобраться и разложить эту кашу по полочкам.
Решение со сторонними сервисами онлайн-трансляций и программ на хостинге/сервере не подходят. Передавать надо сигнал именно из OBS, а не с IP камеры

Comment: Нельзя ли воспользоваться Twitch?

Comment: @IgorR. Увы нет, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы это видео можно было смотреть только на моём сайте и нельзя было перейти на прямую страницу просмотра. Если есть варианты сделать такую защиту (от прямого перехода), то это гораздо удобнее. Сейчас я с использую YouTube, но к сожалению, хоть я и использую свой плеер, посмотрен код элемента можно найти прямую ссылку...

Comment: OBS ведёт вещание по протоколу RTMP, следовательно нужно откуда-то добыть RTMP-сервер. Крайне маловероятно, что он будет на обычных веб-хостингах

Comment: @andreymal А как реализовать RTMP сервер, что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: @Дмитрий ну например скачать и установить nginx-rtmp-module (или готовую сборку с ним) как вариант

Comment: @andreymal куда её установить? Как? Как к ней обращаться?

Comment: @Дмитрий куда-нибудь, куда у вас есть возможность его установить, всё остальное есть в документации nginx и nginx-rtmp-module

Comment: @andreymal Можно установить на хостинг? Как потом обращаться к этому серверу? Вот такой я установил https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module Просто скачал и перекинул. Так же можно? Как его использовать, можете в вкратце рассказать, пожалуйста, без посыла на документацию?

Comment: @Дмитрий еесли у вас возникают такие вопросы, то, видимо, вам требуется пройти какие-нибудь курсы по основам операционных систем, администрированию и устройству компьютерных сетей, ну и по основам программирования на C/C++ заодно на всякий случай

Comment: @andreymal c++ я знаю очень неплохо, но в чём проблема вместо бессмысленных нравоучений, нельзя хотя-бы на русскоязычное обсуждение по этой теме скинуть ссылку?

Comment: @Дмитрий нельзя, потому что все обсуждения подобных тем подразумевают знание основ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal Может поэтому я и задал вопрос здесь? Вы мне как-то поможете или будете ходить вокруг да около?

Comment: @Дмитрий на вопрос я уже давно ответил — нужен RTMP-сервер, и даже привёл пример такого RTMP-сервера. То, что вы принципиально не хотите читать документацию, к вопросу уже не относится.

Comment: @andreymal Хорошо, тогда скажите, где можно развернуть такой RTMP сервер. В документации этого нет

Comment: @Дмитрий на любом устройстве, которое способно запустить nginx и к которому можно подключиться через интернет (можно и на смартфоне, если очень захотеть) и которое способно справиться с планируемой нагрузкой (в первую очередь на трафик, если трансляцию будет смотреть очень много посетителей). Если у вас нет такого устройства, к вашим услугам тысячи хостингов, предоставляющих виртуальные (подешевле) и выделенные (подороже) серверы, с линуксом (подешевле) или виндой (подороже).

Comment: И да, трансляции в браузерах обычно делаются в форматах HLS или MPEG-DASH, принцип которых в делении видео на маленькие файлы (где-то по 2-3 секунды), которые затем скачиваются с сайта браузером по очереди. nginx-rtmp-module умеет создавать такие файлы автоматически при соответствующей настройке. Для браузера в интернете можно найти десятки разных скриптов-плееров, которые могут скачать эти файлы и отобразить видео. Ну и для общего развития, YouTube и Twitch используют формат HLS.